# Rails 4 strong parameters does not work for a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have set a polymorphic association and added a nested form in the view. Im trying to create the main record and the association at the same time. The main record gets created but the association won't.

Here are the two models in question :

```
class UnRegistered < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :vehicle, as: :detailable, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :dealer

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :purchase_details, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :brand
    belongs_to :model
    belongs_to :color
    belongs_to :customer
```

Here's the form definitions :

```
<%= form_for(@un_registered, url: panel_un_registereds_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :vehicle do |f_vehicle| %>
```

Here's a sample params set I get :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "un_registered"=>{"vehicle"=>{"brand_id"=>"", "model_id"=>"", "year"=>"", "engine_number"=>"gdfg", "chassis_number"=>"", "color"=>"", "options"=>""}, "original_price"=>"", "insurance"=>"", "freight"=>"", "tt"=>"", "tt_date"=>"", "duty"=>"", "clearance_fee"=>"", "other_expenses"=>"", "dealer_id"=>"", "landing_date"=>"", "loading_date"=>""}, "controller"=>"panel/un_registereds", "action"=>"create"}
```

Here's the controller actions :

```
def create
     @un_registered = UnRegistered.create(un_registered_params)
end

def un_registered_params
    params.require(:un_registered).permit(:original_price, :insurance, :freight, :tt, :tt_date, :duty, :clearance_fee, :other_expenses, :loading_date, :landing_date, :dealer_id, vehicle_attributes: [:id, :brand_id, :model_id, :engine_number, :chassis_number, :color_id, :year, :options, :selling_price, :customer_id, :purchase_date, :_destroy])
end
```

Full form code :

https://gist.github.com/THPubs/9665e0e5594e15fcc76a

New method :

```
    def new
        @un_registered = UnRegistered.new
    end
```

Comment: I guess you should be having `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in model if you are dealing with `nested_attributes`.

Comment: @Pavan I just added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle` to the `UnRegistered` model and then all the vehicle fields disappeared from the form!

Comment: Could you add the rest of your form code please.

Comment: @Pavan Sure. I added it as a gist : https://gist.github.com/THPubs/9665e0e5594e15fcc76a . Note : Im using angular. But not using angular to submit the form and handle the model creation. It's all rails.

Comment: Your form is OK. I guess you don't have `@un_registered.build_vehicle` in your `new` method in your controller. Please post your new method.

Comment: @Pavan Just posted it. Yes I don't have it! How to add it? Do we assign it to a variable? If assigned to a variable do we need to change the form tag?

Comment: I will explain in my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `form` is fine. You just need to add below changes.

In your `un_registered.rb` model

```
class UnRegistered < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :vehicle, as: :detailable, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :dealer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle #this one
end
```

And in your controller,

```
def new
  @un_registered = UnRegistered.new
  @un_registered.build_vehicle #this one
end
```